# add menu item to default context menu

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I'd like to add a menu item to the default `ContextMenu` of a `RichTextBox`.

I could create a new context menu but then I lose the spell check suggestions that show up in the default menu.

Is there a way to add an item without re-implementing everything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not too tricky to reimplement the RichTextBox context menu with spelling suggestions, Cut, Paste, etc.

Hook up the context menu opening event as follows:

```
AddHandler(RichTextBox.ContextMenuOpeningEvent, new ContextMenuEventHandler(RichTextBox_ContextMenuOpening), true);
```

Within the event handler build the context menu as you need.  You can recreate the existing context menu menu items with the following:

```
private IList<MenuItem> GetSpellingSuggestions()
{
    List<MenuItem> spellingSuggestions = new List();
    SpellingError spellingError = myRichTextBox.GetSpellingError(myRichTextBox.CaretPosition);
    if (spellingError != null)
    {
        foreach (string str in spellingError.Suggestions)
        {
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
            mi.Header = str;
            mi.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            mi.Command = EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError;
            mi.CommandParameter = str;
            mi.CommandTarget = myRichTextBox;
            spellingSuggestions.Add(mi);
        }
    }
    return spellingSuggestions;
}

private IList<MenuItem> GetStandardCommands()
{
    List<MenuItem> standardCommands = new List();

    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
    item.Command = ApplicationCommands.Cut;
    standardCommands.Add(item);

    item = new MenuItem();
    item.Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy;
    standardCommands.Add(item);

    item = new MenuItem();
    item.Command = ApplicationCommands.Paste;
    standardCommands.Add(item);

    return standardCommands;
}
```

If there are spelling errors, you can create Ignore All with:

```
MenuItem ignoreAllMI = new MenuItem();
ignoreAllMI.Header = "Ignore All";
ignoreAllMI.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError;
ignoreAllMI.CommandTarget = textBox;
newContextMenu.Items.Add(ignoreAllMI);
```

Add separators as required.  Add those to the new context menu's items, and then add your shiny new MenuItems.

I'm going to keep looking for a way to obtain the actual context menu though, as this is relevant to something I'll be working on in the near future.

Comment: Thanks, Donnelle.  I figured it would probably come to re-implementing.  Thanks for the tips on how to do this!

Comment: A very similar example can be found directly on MSDN as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.getspellingerror(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Donnelle Sorry for being late to the party, but since I'm facing the exact same problem (except for my scenario having a simple textbox) and this question having the WPF tag, can you provide a more "XAMLish" way, please?

Comment: I'd like to, Yoda, but I haven't worked with XAML in 7 years!