# WPF DataGrid ContextMenu(s)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

How can I define different ContextMenus for each column in the DataGrid (Microsoft's grid)? I found out that the grid provides a `ContextMenu` attribute, but i want different context menu items for the columns, not the same ContextMenu for the whole grid.

Edit: Thanks for your answer! I tried to listen to the `ContextMenuOpeningEvent` as you suggested which was a first success: the ContextMenu can be modified in the EventHandler. But it raises another (hopefully small) problem - I now have to identify the column the mouse cursor was over when the `ContextMenuOpeningEvent` was triggered. I'm going to research how to do (or work around) that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played with it at all, so this might be wrong, but you may be able to override the ContextMenuOpening event and create the appropriate menu on the fly.

[add menu item to default context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210634/add-menu-item-to-default-context-menu) might give you a starting point.

Good luck.