# WPF Richtextbox Default Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, richtextbox, spell-checking

I have a custom RichTextBox control that inherits from WPF's RichTextBox. I want to add the option "Add to dictionary" to the default context menu.

I've scoured the net for tips on accessing the Default context menu of WPF's RichTextBox but can't find anything. I plan on using the solution [Adding menu item to default context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210634/add-menu-item-to-default-context-menu) but I would like to reuse as much of .NET's code and logic before creating my own context menu.

So far, my attempts have only resulted with the default context menu being replaced. The closest I've gotten to adjusting the context menu is when I overrided OnContextMenuOpening method. However, it consistently states the ContextMenu is null.

How do I get access to the default context menu and add my desired option?

---

RichTextBox.ContextMenu is null whenever I examine it, even though the default context menu shows up. If I set the ContextMenu with a new ContextMenu, it replaces the existing context menu with a blank menu.

```
public class CustomRTB : RichTextBox
{
        protected override void OnContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
}
```

Comment: did you mean this "I want to put Context Menu inside my RichTextBox"?

Comment: No. WPF's RichTextBox already utilizes a Context Menu. I want access to that.

Comment: explain "access to that"

Comment: Specifically, RichTextBox.ContextMenu. Whenever I examine it during my tests, its null. However, if I set the ContextMenu with a new ContextMenu, it replaces the existing ContextMenu.

Comment: support your question by your xaml and cs

Comment: @safi Added some code